# VB.net DataGridview: Represent Boolean column using images

Tags: vb.net, image, datagridview

I have a DataGridView `dgv` showing the content of an underlying DataView `dv`, which I use for filtering the row entries. (`dgv.DataSource = dv`)

Two of the columns in the DataView are Boolean types and show up as the default checkbox formatting of VB, however, I would like them to show as squares (or rectangles) in colors red and green for False and True respectively.

I know that for a DataGridView with a column of the type `DataGridViewImageColumn` I could simply generate an image and show it with something similar to this:

```
bmp = New Bitmap(20, 10)
Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
If VarIsValid Then
   g.FillRectangle(Brushes.GreenYellow, 0, 0, bmp.Width - 1, bmp.Height - 1)
Else
   g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 0, 0, bmp.Width - 1, bmp.Height - 1)
End If
g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, bmp.Width - 1, bmp.Height - 1)
End Using
row.Cells("VarIsValid").Value = bmp
```

But I have no Idea how to do something similar with a column originating from a linked DataView; much less when the column is not even an image column.

I considered changing the underlying DataView to contain an image, but then I don't know how I would filter by the value of that column. Thus I hope there is some way to simply change the visualization without changing the underlying structure.

Comment: Could you redraw the cells after the view has loaded?

Comment: Is it possible to alter a column in that way after creating the datagridview and filling in the information? Without breaking the link to the underlying dataview...

Answer (score 1):

Use `Cell Formatting` event handler

```
Private Sub dgv_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellFormatting
    If e.RowIndex < 0 OrElse e.ColumnIndex < 0 Then Exit Sub

    'You can check that column is right by ColumnIndex
    'I prefer using a name of the DataGridViewColumn, 
    'because indexes can be changed while developing
    If Me.dgv.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name.Equals("PredefinedColumnName") = True Then
        If CBool(e.Value) = True Then
            e.Value = My.Resources.GreenSquare 'image saved in the resources
        Else
            e.Value = My.Resources.RedSquare
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

For a simple color fill operation, there is no need to use a bitmap.  Just subscribe to the CellPainting event on the DatagridView.

```
Private Sub dgv1_CellPainting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles dgv1.CellPainting
   Const checkboxColumnIndex As Int32 = 0 ' set this to the needed column index
   If e.ColumnIndex = checkboxColumnIndex AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
      Dim br As Brush
         If CBool(e.Value) Then
            br = Brushes.GreenYellow
         Else
            br = Brushes.Red
         End If
         e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, e.CellBounds)
         e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.Border)
         e.Handled = True
      End If
   End Sub
```

For more information, see:  [Customizing the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171618%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Both your and Fabio's solutions seem along the lines of what I was looking for and I'll probably try both of them before deciding on which one I find more suitable.